# Assiment of vecoter in other vectors in mathematica

Tags: vector, wolfram-mathematica, variable-assignment

If I have these vector let's say

```
d = {34, {e[1] -> 2, e[2] -> 3, e[3] -> 44}}

s = {e[1], e[2], e[3]}
```

why this substitution does not work?

```
s /. d[[2]]
```

or in other word, how can I assign theses values of vector `d[[2]]` in vectors `e`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean the *substitution does not work* ?  When the last line you show is executed Mathematica returns `{2,3,44}` which is exactly what I expect it to.  What do you expect to happen ?

Comment: @ High Performance Mark  when I write e[1] or e[2] they don't have value 2 and 3 as I expected.

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't set values for `e[1]` *etc*, your expectation is fanciful.  I think you need to go back to the early chapters of your favourite Mathematica tutorial and read about `Set`, `SetDelayed`, `Rule` and related matters.

Comment: @ High Performance Mark, do you want to say you know a lot?? you feel better now ha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you ask for:

```
 {e[1],e[2],e[3]}/. {e[1]->2,e[2]->3,e[3]->44}
```

Here is what you get:

```
{2,3,44}
```

This is just what you asked for: you use `ReplaceAll` to **replace** (in the first expression) each of the three variables with the values specified in your rules.  You say that you instead expect the values of these variables to be set, but avoiding such setting is exactly the purpose of the approach you took.  To instead set the values you can just

```
d[[2]] /. {Rule -> Set}
```

But note that you lose the variables in `d` if you do this.